# Using CACLS.EXE in a batch file with auto answer

Tags: windows, batch-file, pipeline

I want to use CACLS.EXE in a batch file with auto answer but have had no success. Following a Microsoft article did not solved my problem (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/135268).

Batch file is:

```
cacls ALF.exe /d everyone
```

If I use it, it asks Y or N questions.  I have tried 2 variants to auto answer the questions:

```
echo y| cacls ALF.exe /d everyone  (Doesn't work)

cacls ALF.exe /d everyone < yes.txt (Doesn't work)
```

I use Windows Ultimate x64. How can I solve that?

Comment: What error message are you getting when you run your command? Whats ALF.exe

Comment: ALF.exe is not important , it is just a portable program , there is no ERROR just ask me : Are you sure ?  I think My cmd ignore pipeline (Strange)

Comment: I had a reason for asking about exe file. Have you tried running the command using a different file like text.txt file or some other file with the switch y.

Comment: I have just tried the command with text.txt and same thing happened No success , it is impossible to eliminate the Are you sure Question , I checked the ComSpec variable path but everything seems normal : %SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe

Comment: I tested the code On windows 8 and works , it seems My windows 7 cmd is damaged
Thanks  for your Answers Chelseawillrecover

Comment: cacls has recently been changed to ICACLS.exe

Answer (score 4):

Interesting, I had the same problem with Windows 8.

I tried this in a command prompt:

```
echo y | cacls.exe [options]...
```

and it did NOT work.

Then I tried:

```
echo y| cacls.exe [options]...
```

and it DID work.  Note I had to remove the space after the 'y' and that fixed it.

Hard to believe but I just did it now on Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you have tried but I have tried this in a batch file **echo y| cacls c:\Troubleshoot\test.txt /d everyone** and it works perfectly.

Note: when you use the switch /d, it wipes every permissions and replaces it with everyone and sets denied access.